# What happened to Johannes Heinrich Louis Munt after his trial in 1945?

Tags: world-war-two, netherlands

I was curious what happend to *Johannes Heinrich Louis Munt*. He was a *SS-Hauptsturmführer and Kriminalkommissar* during World war 2 in the Netherlands.

He ordered the execution of more than 50 people during World War 2. He did not command it himself, but was rather forced to do by a higher command.

Because of that he had to justify his actions after the war in 1945, during the Nuremberg trials. Several documents can be found where you can read his statement during his trial.

Johannes Munt's statement during his trial, only available in Dutch unfortunately.
https://www.tracesofwar.nl/articles/1672/Verklaring-Johannes-Munt-04-06-1945.htm?c=gw

After looking trough all the documents available online and other information about the trials and Johannes Munt himself, I cannot find any information what happend to him after the trials.

Does any historian under us know what happened to him? Did he get executed? Or was he sent to jail? Or has he received no conviction at all?

**Here are some more related sources about *Johannes Munt*.**

- https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piet_Wapperom 
  (Dutch resistance fighter, was somehow saved by Johannes Munt while he should had been
  excuted.)
- https://beeldbankwo2.nl/nl/beelden/detail/dbeebf40-0259-11e7-904b-d89d6717b464 
  Some personal information and a Archive photo of Johannes Munt
- https://forum.axishistory.com/viewtopic.php?t=129799 
  Another guy who tried to get more information regarding Johannes Munt. But only received a few Historical Photos and some links that showed he was in Dutch custody.

I find it odd that there is so little information about him, while you can find much more about others with a high position during Word War 2.

Comment: According to the last post on your axishistory forum link, he was [refused reinstatement in the Hamburg police in 1949](https://recherche.staatsarchiv.hamburg.de/ScopeQuery5.2/detail.aspx?ID=123914), so - if that is correct - I think we can exclude the possibility that he was executed.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Yes, that's correct, I've read that. However, it also could be he wanted to go back into service, but was rejected due to his actions or trial?

Comment: I think it's almost certain that he was rejected because of his actions.  However, the very fact that he applied to be reinstated strongly suggests that he hadn't been executed.

Comment: I agree, so he probably did not receive any conviction at all?

Comment: The canonical source for Dutch WW2 history is Loe de Jong's "Het Koninkrijk der Nederlanden in de Tweede Wereldoorlog". It's searchable online, and mentions [Johannes Munt](http://www.loedejongdigitaal.nl/index/Munt%2C%20J.%20H.%20L.). Specifically, it contains multiple references to a 1947 testimony of Munt.

Comment: And, if he was refused reinstatement in **1949**, presumably any term of imprisonment, if imposed, was very brief?